# Connect a .mdf database to a C# form

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a `.mdf` database called `Persons` in my project in Visual Studio 2012. And have a Windows forms application.

I have a button on the form called `addToDb`. When clicking it, I want to add something to the database.

This is my code:

```
SqlConnection myDbConnection = new SqlConnection ()
myDbConnection.SqlString = "Addr=Persons.mdf;"
```

I don't know the connection string and I find it in the net but it makes for me an error and doesn't open the database connection when I use:

```
myDbConnection.open();
```

> error 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server

Comment: _"it makes for me an error"_ - what error? And what is `Addr`, shouldn't that be `Data Source`?

Comment: To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.

Comment: and at the first of the error it says:error 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

You should refer to www.connectionstrings.com if you do not know the correct connectionstring.

If you use SqlExpress, which I conclude from you .mdf file the syntax would be

```
string connectionString =@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename=c:\path\tofile.mdf; Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
using(SqlConnection myDbconnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
{
  myDbConnection.Open();
  //DoStuff
}
```

Comment: Thanx dear i am new to SQL And databases and dont know difrences between .mdf .sdf databases or forExample dataset and database which is in visual studio.and then the connection way in C#.Can you give me a good resource?

Comment: As harsh as it may sound: just type your question into google. There are oodles and oodles of good blog posts out there, which give you exactly the answer to your question.